# How to resize form text field inputs with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have a form that currently looks like this:

[image]

Except I would like this to all be on one line. To do that, I'm trying to resize the text fields to make them smaller. Basically, I'm adding `col-md-1` to the `div` that encapsulates the `input` tag as follows:

```
    <div className="form-group margin-right-5 col-md-1">
                <input
                    className="form-control"
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='Company' 
                />
            </div>
```

But when I do that, I get this:

[image]

Why is this happening? Is this because `col-md-1` is actually longer than my current text field? Is there any other way that I can make my input fields shorter so that they all fit on one line?

I'm new to bootstrap, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

**[edit]** 
For reference, this is what my code is structured as:

```
    <td>
        <div className="row padding top">
        <div className="row">
        <form action="" className="form-inline form margin-bottom-5">
            <div className="form-group margin-right-5 col-md-1">
                <input
                    className="form-control"
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='Company'
                />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group margin-right-5 col-md-1">
                <input
                    className="form-control"
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='Title'
                />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group margin-right-5">
                <input
                    className="form-control"
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='Start Month'
                />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group margin-right-5">
                <input
                    className="form-control"
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='Start Year'
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <p> - </p>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group margin-right-5">
                <input
                    className="form-control"
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='End Month'
                />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group margin-right-5">
                <input
                    className="form-control"
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='End Year'
                />
            </div>

        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </td>
```

Comment: 1. You have a row inmediately inside a row. That's wrong. 2. You should not mess up with cols margins / padding, you will break bootstrap. 3. Best thing would be to create a row, inside that the cols you need and inside each col the form-group.

Comment: Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/ofd8ygb3/